# How to resume a parent section in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, sections

I would like to be able to resume composing within a parent section after I have already created a sub-section. e.g.:

```
=section 1=
some section 1 text

==sub-section 1.1==
some sub-section 1.1 text
==sub-section 1.2==
some sub-section 1.2 text

done with sub-sections 1.1, 1.2  and want to resume more section 1
```

Is there a way to do this? I find it a bit awkward to always have to push all sub-sections to the end.

Comment: That's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest fudging this with creating new classes in your common css style sheet. Make a class called 'subsection' there and have the code set the text in that div section apart from the rest of the text around it ---

```
div#subsection {
margin: 6px;  
padding: 10px;
padding-right: 12px; 
background: yellow; 
border: 1px solid black; 
padding: 1em;
}
```

That example is garishly coloured so you can see more easily how it works. Then just stuff it into your page under the heading, like so ---

```
== Alice in Wonderland ==

Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do. Once or twice she had peeped into the
book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
it, "and what is the use of a book," thought Alice, "without pictures or
conversations?"

<div id="subsection">
=== About Alice ===
You may have noticed Alice is a bit of a drip. 
</div>

So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the
day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of
making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and
picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran
close by her.
```

And so on. When a TOC is generated, it should have that separate bit listed as a subsection of the parent heading. The formatting there is weird - you'll probably want to fuss with floats and margins and things - but hopefully it gives you the general idea of what to do. You can make the subsection style as unobtrusive as you like so it can blend seamlessly with the rest of the page.

It's not the most convenient bit of code, but for the purpose of style and page layout, it works. This is also a handy trick for making sidebars.